# swagger generate class with NSCoding for swift 3

Tags: ios, swift3, swagger, generated-code, swagger-codegen

I am working with swagger and I just generated classes for swift 3. But while developing my application, when I wanted to save my Objects to UserDefaults my app crash, because of my classes are not extending NSCoding, I think. There is a command for swift 3 to generate my Classes with NSCoding ? There is my command to generate my classes :

```
java -jar swagger-codegen-cli-2.2.2.jar generate -i illicity.yaml -l swift3 -DserializableModel=true -o Swift/
```

the : `-DserializableModel=true` works for java/android generated class.

Thanks.

### Solve my problem :

So I have write my own model to have serializable with NSCoding in my classes. Here is the mustache model :

```
{{#models}}
{{#model}}
//
// {{classname}}.swift
//
// Generated by swagger-codegen
// https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen
//

import Foundation

{{#description}}

/** {{description}} */{{/description}}
{{#isArrayModel}}
public typealias {{classname}} = [{{arrayModelType}}]
{{/isArrayModel}}
{{^isArrayModel}}
{{#isEnum}}
public enum {{classname}}: {{dataType}} {
{{#allowableValues}}{{#enumVars}}    case {{name}} = "{{{value}}}"
{{/enumVars}}{{/allowableValues}}
    func encodeToJSON() -> Any { return self.rawValue }
}
{{/isEnum}}
{{^isEnum}}
{{#vars.isEmpty}}
public typealias {{classname}} = {{dataType}}
{{/vars.isEmpty}}
{{^vars.isEmpty}}
open class {{classname}}: NSObject, NSCoding {{#parent}}{{{parent}}}{{/parent}}{{^parent}},JSONEncodable{{/parent}} {

{{#vars}}
{{#isEnum}}
    public enum {{enumName}}: {{^isContainer}}{{datatype}}{{/isContainer}}{{#isContainer}}String{{/isContainer}} { {{#allowableValues}}{{#enumVars}}
        case {{name}} = {{#isContainer}}"{{/isContainer}}{{#isString}}"{{/isString}}{{{value}}}{{#isString}}"{{/isString}}{{#isContainer}}"{{/isContainer}}{{/enumVars}}{{/allowableValues}}
    }
{{/isEnum}}
{{/vars}}
{{#vars}}
{{#isEnum}}
    {{#description}}/** {{description}} */
    {{/description}}public var {{name}}: {{{datatypeWithEnum}}}{{^unwrapRequired}}?{{/unwrapRequired}}{{#unwrapRequired}}{{^required}}?{{/required}}{{/unwrapRequired}}{{#defaultValue}} = {{{defaultValue}}}{{/defaultValue}}
{{/isEnum}}
{{^isEnum}}
    {{#description}}/** {{description}} */
    {{/description}}public var {{name}}: {{{datatype}}}{{^unwrapRequired}}?{{/unwrapRequired}}{{#unwrapRequired}}{{^required}}?{{/required}}{{/unwrapRequired}}{{#defaultValue}} = {{{defaultValue}}}{{/defaultValue}}
{{/isEnum}}
{{/vars}}

{{#additionalPropertiesType}}
    public var additionalProperties: [AnyHashable:{{{additionalPropertiesType}}}] = [:]

{{/additionalPropertiesType}}
{{^unwrapRequired}}
    {{^parent}}public override init() {}{{/parent}}{{/unwrapRequired}}
{{#unwrapRequired}}
    public init({{#allVars}}{{^-first}}, {{/-first}}{{name}}: {{#isEnum}}{{datatypeWithEnum}}{{/isEnum}}{{^isEnum}}{{datatype}}{{/isEnum}}{{^required}}?=nil{{/required}}{{/allVars}}) {
        {{#vars}}
        self.{{name}} = {{name}}
        {{/vars}}
    }{{/unwrapRequired}}

    public required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder){
        {{#vars}}
        {{#isEnum}}
        self.{{name}} = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "{{name}}") as? {{{datatypeWithEnum}}}
        {{/isEnum}}
        {{^isEnum}}
        self.{{name}} = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "{{name}}") as? {{{datatype}}}
        {{/isEnum}}
        {{/vars}}
    }
{{#additionalPropertiesType}}
    public subscript(key: AnyHashable) -> {{{additionalPropertiesType}}}? {
        get {
            if let value = additionalProperties[key] {
                return value
            }
            return nil
        }

        set {
            additionalProperties[key] = newValue
        }
    }
{{/additionalPropertiesType}}
    // MARK: JSONEncodable
    {{#parent}}override {{/parent}}open func encodeToJSON() -> Any {
        var nillableDictionary = {{#parent}}super.encodeToJSON() as? [String:Any?] ?? {{/parent}}[String:Any?](){{#vars}}{{#isNotContainer}}{{#isPrimitiveType}}{{^isEnum}}{{#isInteger}}
        nillableDictionary["{{baseName}}"] = self.{{name}}{{^unwrapRequired}}?{{/unwrapRequired}}{{#unwrapRequired}}{{^required}}?{{/required}}{{/unwrapRequired}}.encodeToJSON(){{/isInteger}}{{#isLong}}
        nillableDictionary["{{baseName}}"] = self.{{name}}{{^unwrapRequired}}?{{/unwrapRequired}}{{#unwrapRequired}}{{^required}}?{{/required}}{{/unwrapRequired}}.encodeToJSON(){{/isLong}}{{^isLong}}{{^isInteger}}
        nillableDictionary["{{baseName}}"] = self.{{name}}{{/isInteger}}{{/isLong}}{{/isEnum}}{{/isPrimitiveType}}{{#isEnum}}
        nillableDictionary["{{baseName}}"] = self.{{name}}{{^unwrapRequired}}?{{/unwrapRequired}}{{#unwrapRequired}}{{^required}}?{{/required}}{{/unwrapRequired}}.rawValue{{/isEnum}}{{^isPrimitiveType}}
        nillableDictionary["{{baseName}}"] = self.{{name}}{{^unwrapRequired}}?{{/unwrapRequired}}{{#unwrapRequired}}{{^required}}?{{/required}}{{/unwrapRequired}}.encodeToJSON(){{/isPrimitiveType}}{{/isNotContainer}}{{#isContainer}}{{^isEnum}}
        nillableDictionary["{{baseName}}"] = self.{{name}}{{^unwrapRequired}}?{{/unwrapRequired}}{{#unwrapRequired}}{{^required}}?{{/required}}{{/unwrapRequired}}.encodeToJSON(){{/isEnum}}{{#isEnum}}{{#isListContainer}}
        nillableDictionary["{{baseName}}"] = self.{{name}}{{^unwrapRequired}}?{{/unwrapRequired}}{{#unwrapRequired}}{{^required}}?{{/required}}{{/unwrapRequired}}.map({$0.rawValue}).encodeToJSON(){{/isListContainer}}{{#isMapContainer}}//TODO: handle enum map scenario{{/isMapContainer}}{{/isEnum}}{{/isContainer}}{{/vars}}

        {{#additionalPropertiesType}}
        for (key, value) in additionalProperties {
            if let key = key as? String {
               nillableDictionary[key] = value
            }
        }

        {{/additionalPropertiesType}}
        let dictionary: [String:Any] = APIHelper.rejectNil(nillableDictionary) ?? [:]
        return dictionary
    }

    public func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder) {
        {{#vars}}
        aCoder.encode({{name}}, forKey: "{{name}}")
        {{/vars}}
    }
}
{{/vars.isEmpty}}
{{/isEnum}}
{{/isArrayModel}}
{{/model}}
{{/models}}
```

I think some improvements can be done. But this is what I wanted.

Comment: There is this open issue about it https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/issues/3596 As a workaround, you could modify the Model mustache template to include it https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/blob/master/modules/swagger-codegen/src/main/resources/swift3/model.mustache

Comment: Thank you I will write the model and post it here and on the issue